Keen-slider: Slides appear all at once without spacing on initial page load
I'm using a route transition and when I refresh the page, I can see how slides appear all at once without spacing, and after the page is fully loaded they fall into place and are displayed correctly. I suppose the slider may be initializing before all elements and styles are fully loaded and applied, leading to incorrect spacing and layout initially. I tried putting the logic in onMounted and using nextTick, but it freezes the carousel instead.
Reproduction of the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-ubrvzh?file=app.vue
Steps to reproduce:
If you don't use a route transition, select throttling profile like 'Slow 4G' in the 'Network' section of the browser and reload the page to see the issue.
